# Dynamic changes in resources, Windows Phone

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making some changes to resources in runtime to prepare application for different (physical) screen sizes:

```
var info = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
Size screenSize = new Size(Math.Round(Window.Current.Bounds.Width * info.RawPixelsPerViewPixel),
    Math.Round(Window.Current.Bounds.Height * info.RawPixelsPerViewPixel));

Application.Current.Resources["SmallerText"] = (1.0 / 15.0) * screenSize.Height / info.RawDpiY * 72;
Application.Current.Resources["SmallText"] = (1.0 / 12.0) * screenSize.Height / info.RawDpiY * 72;
Application.Current.Resources["MediumText"] = (1.0 / 10.0) * screenSize.Height / info.RawDpiY * 72;
Application.Current.Resources["LargeText"] = (1.0 / 5.0) * screenSize.Height / info.RawDpiY * 72;
var displayMargin = (1.0 / 320.0) * screenSize.Height;
Application.Current.Resources["DisplayMargin"] = new Thickness(displayMargin);
```

Now when I try to use modified font sizes, it works:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BaseButton">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource SmallText}" />
```

But when I try to use modified Thickness, application crashes:

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="{StaticResource DisplayMargin}">
```

Error message is quite enigmatic:

```
An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in MyApp.exe but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Failed to assign to property '%0'. [Line: 17 Position: 50]

Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.



Failed to assign to property '%0'. [Line: 17 Position: 50]

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Why can't I use modified Thickness? If I don't modify it from the code behind, everything works correctly.

---

**Edit:** Workarounds

Workaround #1:

```
var displayMargin = (1.0 / 320.0) * screenSize.Height;
Application.Current.Resources.Remove("DisplayMargin");
Application.Current.Resources.Add("DisplayMargin", new Thickness(displayMargin));
```

Workaround #2:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="{ThemeResource DisplayMargin}">
```

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware App.xaml.cs

Comment: I've tried your code and it seems to work fine on my phone - [here is a sample project](http://1drv.ms/1yzlVxt) - can you check it?